# Not getting milliseconds while executedataset in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

i am not able to get milliseconds for DataTable which one of the column is datetime.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    if (mustCloseConnection)
        sqlConnection.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

without milliseconds date and time value alone is coming.

LoggedIn column is one of the clustered primary key in database table.

we need to update or delete based on this filed also.

If milliseconds is .000 then it is working fine
   else 
it is problem to delete or update

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
object loggedIn = dt.Rows[0]["LoggedIn"];
```

Comment: What code are you using to try to do that?

Comment: @Guffa : i had updated the question.

Comment: That's good, but it only shows how you get the data set. It's likely that the data set contains all the information, and you lose the millliseconds when you display the data from the data set. How do you get the DateTime values from the data set, and what do you do with the value to display it?

Comment: Is the column `datetime` or `datetime2` and if the latter, what is the precision specifier?

Comment: @Guffa : i had updated the question.

Comment: @mdisibio : it is datetime

Comment: Ok, next step: You are getting the value into an `object` variable. At that stage it's still a `DateTime` value. What are you doing with this value to see what it contains? Note that the `datetime` value in the database doesn't have millisecond precision, only 1/300 second precision.